# Do I need to do some registration of floatformat tag in django before using it?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following piece of code

```
 <div>{{ context_findings["overdue_findings"]  }} | {{ (context_findings["overdue_findings"] / context_findings["total_findings"] * 100)|floatformat  }}%</div>
```

but on executing it I get the error

```
TemplateSyntaxError 
("no filter named 'floatformat'",)
```

I've tried doing something like

```
<div class="pb-2">Overdue {{ 1.223|floatformat }}</div>
```

to see if it works but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: You can not perform dictionary lookups, and do calculus in Django templates, so `context_findings["overdue_findings"] / context_findings["total_findings"] * 100` will not work.

Comment: Are you using Django or Jinja?

Comment: I'm using Django

Comment: but the second example should atleast work right?

Comment: normally yes. I managed to run this and got `1.2` as result. Are you sure the error is not on a different line where you use `floatfield`?